# Filter list data based on page Url

Tags: 2010, list, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a relatively small SharePoint list. When a user comes to the list page I want a generalized list to display with a search box. I want this list to have no parameters or variables attached to it so that it can be wildcard (*) searched.
This way whenever the wildcard is inserted into the search box the default list displays all results.

This page will have a second list view with several parameters and filters already set on it.
When someone types the search criteria in the parameters and filters goes to work searching for what the person is looking for.

I have both list views already set up.

How do I set the page (programmably) to toggle between my list views based on the url parameter value.

Example: http://mysite.com/allitems.aspx?search=all
default view shows all results.

http://mysite.com/allitems.aspx?product=fruit
shows only the product listings that are fruit

Comment: I updated the title to more accurately reflect your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to grab the parameter and hide or show the web part.

Though it may be simpler to change how you link to the page.  Instead of changing the parameter link to the view you want to see?

Comment: Dave I think you may have hit the nail on the head with your suggestion to interlink the pages with the different views. I essentially already have both pages complete. All I would need to do is check the javascript and jQuery to insure that the search criterias are pointing to the correct view. Thank you.

Comment: Also I wanted to let you know that your answer essentially answers my other question on a related topic. I thought you may want to post your answer here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67713/is-there-a-way-to-remove-code-from-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: That is great news - well done

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for either the [Text Filter Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-data-view-web-part-HA010250997.aspx) or the [Query String Filter Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx) which do something pretty close to that.  It doesn't change the view but it does filter the results based on the text entered.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that was my initial thought as well. However, neither seem to be working with the listview webpart that has all of the filters and parameters. If you could provide me to a method that will work with this part I would be fine. The problem here is I already have sever parameters and filters in place through SharePoint designer.